# MySQL Add results to query based on results

Tags: mysql

I know the title is vague and this might be hard for me to explain but this is what I am trying to accomplish.

Say I have a table called articles.

In that table, I have an id, password, file, group, etc....

I want to do a query where password='thispassword'. Easy enough.

But then join that somehow where the results of that query also include where group=file

```
id | password  | file   | group
----------------------------------
1  | passA     | 1filea | group1
2  | passB     | 2fileb | group1
3  |           | group1 | 
4  | passD     | 4filed | group2
5  | passD     | 5filee | group2
6  |           | group2 |
```

With the table above if I query for passA (WHERE password='passA') it has **group1** in the group column. I want to also return within the same query WHERE the file equals group1 which would be id: 3 in the above table.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "this might be hard for me to explain".  So how do you expect us to help you if it's too hard for you to explain what you want to do?

Comment: I explained it the best I could. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we could use the MySQL logical `OR` operator to satisfy the specification.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or

```
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.password = 'passA' 
    OR t.file     = 'group1'
```

Given the sample data, we would expect this to return two rows, id values 1 and 3.

The specification isn't entirely clear. We can combine multiple conditions to get a different result:

```
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE ( t.password IN ('passA','') OR t.password IS NULL )
   AND t.file     = 'group1'
```

---

*EDIT*

If I'm understanding the specification, the value in the `group` column is a foreign key to the `file` column.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.password
     , t.file
     , t.group
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.password = 'passA'

 UNION ALL

SELECT f.id
     , f.password
     , f.file
     , f.group
  FROM mytable g
  JOIN mytable f
    ON f.file = g.group
 WHERE g.password = 'passA'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, group1 comes from the results under group ...  WHERE password='passA'. So group1 isn't part of the initial query. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: providing an example of the expected output would help demonstrate the specification. I took another guess at what the specification is, and provided a query that satisfies that interpretation of the spec.